# How does the packets go out even behind Firewall or NAT with some application?

Tags: security, networking, audio, network-programming, voice

Such as Skype/Team viewer/Logmein etc application, which send audio/video behind NAT (behind firewall). But when i make a small tiny application which send text to another NAT location it failed to do the same.

```
Example: 

Sender: 
-> Public ip: 91.1.2.3 My lan ip is: 192.168.1.2 with port 14446 udp
-------> Data format: RTP packets
Receiver:
<------- Data received: 0 packets
-> Public ip: 92.1.2.3 Friend lan ip is: 10.0.0.2 with port 14446 udp

* same in both way
```

How others does this? What is the way of doing peer 2 peer application development to overcome NAT issues? Always we have public ip's and mostly it has NAT issues.

But how does then Skype works in such cases too? Do we have a audio/video port range for UDP or always UDP is open from anything? But mine does not work above range ports for UDP i also tried. What is the secret? that is making me curious!!.

**Note:** 
My goal is audio packets handling where i believe too much filtering or firewall cause latency and delay and other issues gets involved relatively too. So i would like to know very clearly for my application that some of the ports (which port ranges?) can be used for such purposes, where it really not blocking development stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of types of NATs, which vary in what traffic they'll allow in.

See the [Wikipedia article on NATs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

For most NATs, STUN will let you open ports AND find out what port you opened (may be different than the port you sent from).  In SIP and RTSP you'd typically provide the external IP and port determined by STUN to the other end.

A fully-symmetric NAT means that STUN won't let you use a 3rd-party server to prop ports via STUN, so you'll have to use UPnP (if enabled) or map ports in the router (or set up triggers), or you'll have to play evil games to make both sides think they initiated the connection.  (Not easy and not guaranteed.)

See the ICE & TURN specs (RFCs) from the IETF for detailed mechanisms to traverse NATs - though note that in some cases you must use an external proxy to forward packets.

Comment: Great info. But still we are dealing with latency. The idea that i am trying to implement is A) Shake hands (for no firewall/NAT issues) B) by pass raw packets from user1 to user2 without involving a switch/proxy server to deal the Media packets. Because in my research and experiments, it has been proved that peer 2 peer media should not involved third party filtering. And the main goal is lowest latency in media.

Comment: Read the articles I referenced.  You can't easily handle the case of a fully-symmetric router without control of the router; certainly not fully-symmtric routers at both ends without some type of RTP proxy/forwarder (see ICE/TURN).  You can deal with symmetric routers via UPnP (if enabled) or manual port-mapping.  I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "Shake hands".  Low latency communication will be better if you can avoid a proxy - ICE lets you determine if there's a way to avoid relay.

Comment: Are those IPv6 compatible? Or they will be removed and suspended technologies when IPv4 does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

One common solution is that the client program connects outward to the server and thus establishes a connection.  Most firewalls allow outward connections - the assumption being that you are trusted and can always connect to the outside.  When the server then wishes to send a message to you, it responds on the open connection.

Comment: A (behind firewall), B (friend behind firewall), C (Server stun/nat mapper). A connects C and C connects A and A register to C? or A connects B but cant communicate because of behind NAT. or A and B in telephone talks about there negotiation information and try to establish behind NAT mapping? What exactly you mean, is STUN which is only a public ip and public port maps, but still its A to B.

Comment: What I meant was: A connects to C and thus determines its external IP/Port.  That's all STUN does.  The C server owner can now declare that A is online and reachable on this external IP/Port.  B can therefore connect directly to A.  C would not be involved in the direct communication.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the port that you use is what is usually used to determine if it should be allowed or not. Certain ports are always let through. I'm not sure of the exact ports, but that will be different for all NATs and firewalls.